# Combining extension methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, enums, extension-methods

I'm trying to write 2 extension methods to handle Enum types. One to use the description attribute to give some better explanation to the enum options and a second method to list the enum options and their description to use in a selectlist or some kind of collection.

You can read my code up to now here:

```
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function ToDescriptionString(ByVal en As System.Enum) As String

        Dim type As Type = en.GetType
        Dim entries() As String = en.ToString().Split(","c)
        Dim description(entries.Length) As String

        For i = 0 To entries.Length - 1
            Dim fieldInfo = type.GetField(entries(i).Trim())
            Dim attributes() = DirectCast(fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), False), DescriptionAttribute())

            description(i) = If(attributes.Length > 0, attributes(0).Description, entries(i).Trim())
        Next

        Return String.Join(", ", description)

    End Function

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function ToListFirstTry(ByVal en As System.Enum) As IEnumerable

        Dim type As Type = en.GetType

        Dim items = From item In System.Enum.GetValues(type) _
           Select New With {.Value = item, .Text = item.ToDescriptionString}

        Return items

    End Function

    <Extension()> _
    Public Function ToListSecondTry(ByVal en As System.Enum) As IEnumerable

        Dim list As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
        Dim enumValues As Array = System.Enum.GetValues(en.GetType)

        For Each value In enumValues
            list.Add(value, value.ToDescriptionString)
        Next

        Return list

    End Function
```

So my problem is both extension methods don't work that well together. The methods that converts the enum options to an ienumerable can't use the extension method to get the description.

I found all kind of examples to do one of both but never in combination with each other. What am I doing wrong? I still new to these new .NET 3.5 stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Enum.GetValues` just returns a weakly typed `Array`.

Try this:

```
Public Function ToListFirstTry(ByVal en As System.Enum) As IEnumerable

    Dim type As Type = en.GetType

    Dim items = From item In System.Enum.GetValues(type).Cast(Of Enum)() _
       Select New With {.Value = item, .Text = item.ToDescriptionString}

    Return items

End Function
```

(It looks like explicitly typed range variables in VB queries don't mean the same thing as in C#.)

Comment: I tried doing that but then I get this error: "Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'System.Enum'." on the "As Enum" part.